# Search a folder of files for a keyword, copy offset data from the reoccurring keyword to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, search, paste, keyword

I need to create code that does the following:

1. Searches a destination folder that contains hundreds of excel sheets
2. Looks for the string "Current Risk" (the cell containing the string Current Risk is merged&centered - does this count as Column 1?)
3. Once the keyword is found, copies and pastes data in different columns under the equipment ID that is:

   3a) (2,2) from the keyword [this will return the ID from attached picture below]

   3b) (5,3) from the keyword [this will return the corrosion rate from the picture]

   3c) (5,4) from the keyword [ this will return the remaining half-life from the picture]
4. There will be other boxes lower down with the same Current Risk target word but with different equipment IDs.
   We need to collect all this data again for the next equipment ID for each encounter of the word Current Risk. So loop down the sheet collecting all the current risk data with each encounter and then onto the next workbook in the folder and repeat.
5. Paste all this data into a new master Workbook.

Code for a previous project that might give a head start. This code looked for keywords at the top of a column and pasted the whole column's data into a new master workbook head-to-tail one after another.

```vb
Sub Merges()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFilesLike As String
    Dim strPathName As String
    Dim strCurrentFile As String
    pth = "C:\Users\phil\Desktop\Reports\MASTER\" 
    Set tgt = Workbooks.Open(pth & "master file.xlsx") 
    strPathName = "C:\Users\phil\Reports\MASTER\Data\" 
    strFilesLike = "*.xls*"
    strFileName = strPathName & strFilesLike
    strCurrentFile = Dir(strFileName)
    Do While strCurrentFile <> ""
    
        ' Combine file data code goes here
        Set src = Workbooks.Open(strPathName & strCurrentFile)
        Set dest = tgt.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Set src = ActiveWorkbook
        
        With src.Sheets("Hierarchy Item Attributes") 
            Set colh = .Range("1:1").Find("Hierarchy Item Site")
            cnt = Cells(Rows.Count, colh.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1
            dest.Resize(cnt).Value = colh.Offset(1).Resize(cnt).Value
        
            Set colh = .Range("1:1").Find("Hierarchy Item Address") 
            dest.Offset(, 1).Resize(cnt).Value = colh.Offset(1).Resize(cnt).Value 
            On Error Resume Next 
        
            Set colh = .Range("1:1").Find("Hierarchy Item Address") 
            dest.Offset(, 2).Resize(cnt).Value = colh.Offset(1).Resize(cnt).Value
        
            Set colh = .Range("1:1").Find("Hierarchy Item Name")
            dest.Offset(, 3).Resize(cnt).Value = colh.Offset(1).Resize(cnt).Value
                 
        End With
        src.Close False
        ' Get next file to Import
        strCurrentFile = Dir
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Picture of one of the xlsm sheets to search
[image]

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having when trying to adapt this code to your current requirements?  Note the questions which amount to "please modify this code according to my listed specifications" typically do not get a good reception here - you need to tell us what you tried, and how the outcome was different from what you expected.

Comment: Thanks for responding Tim. I am a complete beginner. I can understand basic lines and change coordinates but I don't fully understand what a lot of the lines do. So using the above I know how the top half will cycle through a folder and I know I need to search the range A:A for Current Risk. But I don't know how to save the results as a variable or array and how to paste those results to a destination with an offset.

Comment: This question could be split into 4 threads. 1. "How can I find all excel workbooks that contain specific data?", 2. "How can I copy data to a known list of excel workbooks?", 3. "How can I copy data into a table based on Header & Row ID?", 4. "How can I compile data from multiple workbooks into a master workbook?". Not to mention, each of these threads already exists on this website and as tutorials elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I'm not really getting paid by my company to sit for a week solid to learn programming. let's just end this here, I can see it's not going to go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a new Master workbook. Use `FindNext` to continue the search.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Merges()
       
    Const PTH = "C:\Users\phil\Desktop\Reports\MASTER\"
    Const TERM = "Current Risk"
        
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim strFileName As String, strFilesLike As String
    Dim strPathName As String, strCurrentFile As String
    Dim strMaster As String
    Dim r As Long, n As Long
    Dim rng As Range, first As String
    
    Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Add(1)
    Set wsMaster = wbMaster.Sheets(1)
    With wsMaster
         .Name = "Master"
         .Range("A1:D1") = Array("ID", "Corrosion Rate", "Half Life", "Sheet")
    End With
    r = 2
    
    strPathName = PTH & "Data1\"
    strFilesLike = "*.xls*"
    strFileName = strPathName & strFilesLike
    strCurrentFile = Dir(strFileName)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While strCurrentFile <> ""
       
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPathName & strCurrentFile, True, True)
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            With ws.UsedRange
                Set rng = .Find(TERM, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count))
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    first = rng.Address
                    Do
                        wsMaster.Cells(r, 1) = ws.Cells(rng.Row + 1, "B") 'ID
                        wsMaster.Cells(r, 2) = ws.Cells(rng.Row + 8, "E") 'Corrision Rate
                        wsMaster.Cells(r, 3) = ws.Cells(rng.Row + 8, "F") 'Half Life
                        wsMaster.Cells(r, 4) = wb.Name & " " & ws.Name & " row " & rng.Row
                        r = r + 1
                        Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
                     Loop While rng.Address <> first
                 End If
             End With
        Next
        wb.Close False
        
        ' Get next file to Import
        strCurrentFile = Dir
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' save
    strMaster = PTH & "master_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss")
    wbMaster.SaveAs strMaster
    'wbMaster.Close
    MsgBox n & " files scanned into " & strMaster, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you CDP1802, I am very grateful. Could I have your PayPal email address so that I can send you a tip?  I couldn't get this to work at first but I played about with it and learned some things - I find that is the best way for me to learn - to reverse engineer the code that is written. I got it to work by deleting the & "Data1/" from this part: strPathName = PTH & "Data1\". Could you explain what this does? Why do we want to add the text Data1 to the path?

Comment: @00fil00 I think I missread you paths `C:\Users\phil\Desktop\Reports\MASTER\ ` and  `C:\Users\phil\Reports\MASTER\Data\ `  I thought the second was the first with `Data\ ` added